# JQuery-steps dynamically add steps to a form and pass all of the objects to the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-steps

I have a form and this form can dynamically have 1 - *n* records added to it before it's passed to the controller with data.

This is the ViewModel of the form

```
public class AddFieldDataViewModel
{

    public int SampleID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartCollectionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartCollectionTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime StopCollectionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StopCollectionTime { get; set; }
    public double FlowVolume { get; set; }

}
```

...and the view

```
@model MyApplication.Areas.FP.Models.AddFieldDataViewModel

@{
Layout = null;
string name = "Field Data";
string id = "steps-form";
string action = "AddFieldDataLog";
string target = "FieldDatasContent";
string ajax = "FieldDataLoader";
}
<div class="modal-header">
@MyHelper.ModalCloseButton()
<h3 class="modal-title">
    Add <small>@name</small>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(actionName: action, routeValues: null, 
htmlAttributes: new { id = id, @class = "form-horizontal" }, ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = target,
    OnSuccess = "closeModal",
    LoadingElementId = ajax
}))
{  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h3>Step One</h3>
    <section>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SampleID, "SampleID", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SampleID, "SampleID", new { @class = "form-control date", type = "text" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SampleID, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartCollectionDate, "Start Collection Date", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartCollectionDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control date", type = "text" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartCollectionDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartCollectionTime, "Start Collection Time", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartCollectionTime, "{0:hh\\:mm}", new { @class = "form-control time", type = "text" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartCollectionTime, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StopCollectionDate, "Stop Collection Date", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StopCollectionDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control date", type = "text" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StopCollectionDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StopCollectionTime, "Stop Collection Time", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StopCollectionTime, "{0:hh\\:mm}", new { @class = "form-control time", type = "text" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StopCollectionTime, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FlowVolume, "Flow Volume", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FlowVolume, new { @class = "form-control time", type = "text" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FlowVolume, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
</div>

<script>
    $('#steps-form').steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        enableAllSteps: true,
        enablePagination: true,
        autoAdjustHeight: true,
        showFinishButtonAlways: true,
        enableKeyNavigation: true,
        enableCancelButton: true,
        stepsOrientation: "vertical",
        transitionEffect: "slide",
        labels: {
            finish: "Submit"
        },

        onCanceled: function (event) {
            var modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
            modal.modal('hide');
            clearModal(modal);
        },
        onFinished: () => $("form#steps-form").submit()
    });

</script>
```

What I would like to achieve is have a button next to the Previous and Next buttons [Much like this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915407/how-to-have-two-buttons-in-jquery-steps) and have that button add new steps to the form that have new ViewModel properties. What I can't figure out is how to add new ViewModel properties to the form via the `add` method from JQuery-steps [seen here in the Wiki](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Methods). I've tried following the [Dynamic Manipulation example](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#manipulation) but I am still not able to add a new form/new set of properties. What I have tried is taking all of the properties from the view model out into their own `cshtml` file and in the `add` method try to reference them via `@Html.Partial("_FieldDataProperties")` but this breaks the link in the example below. The only thing that shows up on the page is `))">Add`. If I remove the Partial view HTML helper and leave the add method by itself I'm able to add blank steps to the form.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"onclick="$('#steps-form').steps
('add',@Html.Partial("_FieldDataProperties"));">Add</a></div>
```

This is the ViewModel properties in their standalone view

```
@model MyApplication.Areas.FP.Models.AddFieldDataModel
@{ Layout = null;}
title:  ``,
content: `<section>
 <div class="form-group">
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SampleID, "SampleID", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SampleID, Model.SIDs, "Select SampleId", new { @class = "form-control select-chosen" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SampleID, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartCollectionDate, "Start Collection Date", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartCollectionDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control date", type = "text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartCollectionDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartCollectionTime, "Start Collection Time", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartCollectionTime, "{0:hh\\:mm}", new { @class = "form-control time", type = "text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartCollectionTime, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StopCollectionDate, "Stop Collection Date", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StopCollectionDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control date", type = "text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StopCollectionDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StopCollectionTime, "Stop Collection Time", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StopCollectionTime, "{0:hh\\:mm}", new { @class = "form-control time", type = "text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StopCollectionTime, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FlowVolume, "Flow Volume", new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" })
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FlowVolume, new { @class = "form-control time", type = "text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FlowVolume, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
</section>`
```

I have been able to create a list of objects using LINQ and have JQuery-Steps iterate over the list and create forms that way and it works perfectly. However, I am not able to create steps dynamically with the properties. Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly? I'm rather new(ish) when it comes to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed up the JavaScript and this creates the steps like I need it to.

```
<script>
    $('#steps-form').steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        enableAllSteps: true,
        enablePagination: true,
        autoAdjustHeight: true,
        showFinishButtonAlways: true,
        enableKeyNavigation: true,
        enableCancelButton: true,
        stepsOrientation: "vertical",
        transitionEffect: "slide",
        titleTemplate: '#title#',
        labels: {
            finish: "Submit"
        },
        onInit: function(event, currentIndex){

                var addA = $("<a>").attr("href", "#").addClass("btn btn-primary").text("Add");
                var addBtn = $("<li>").attr("aria-disabled", false).append(addA);
                $(document).find(".actions ul").prepend(addBtn)
                addBtn.on("click", function () { $('#steps-form').steps('add', {@Html.Partial("_FieldDataProperties") }).steps("next"); });

        },
        onCanceled: function (event) {
            var modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
            modal.modal('hide');
            clearModal(modal);
        },
        onFinished: () => $("form#steps-form").submit()

    });

</script>
```